# Python: Making a list of valid results from list of measurements

Tags: python

I'm having some problems with writing a function in python. It's called with a list of integers (measurements) and it needs to check each of them for a valid measurement (delta of 0.1 compared to next element). And it needs to store them in new list with true/false on same indexes.

```
def mark_veljavne(s):
b = []
a = 0
for f in s:
    if len(s) == 1:
        b.append(True)
        break
    if a == 0:
        if abs(s[0] - s[1]) > 0.1:
            b.append(True)
            a += 1
        else:
            b.append(False)
            a += 1
    if a == (len(s) - 1):
        if abs(s[a] - s[a - 1]) > 0.1:
            b.append(True)
            break
        else:
            b.append(False)
            break
    if abs(s[a] - s[a - 1]) > 0.1 and abs(s[a] - s[a + 1]) > 0.1 and a != 0:
        b.append(True)
        a += 1
    elif a != 0:
        b.append(False)
        a += 1
return b
```

[Link to test in pastebin, since they get shown in one line](http://pastebin.com/EZ0FAELc)

```
def test_oznaci_veljavne(self): self.assertEqual(oznaci_veljavne([5.18, 5.907, 6.632, 7.215]), [True] * 4) self.assertEqual(oznaci_veljavne([132.3, 132.94]), [True] * 2) self.assertEqual(oznaci_veljavne([183.12]), [True]) self.assertEqual(oznaci_veljavne([205.134, 205.182, 205.190, 205.207]), [False] * 4) self.assertEqual(oznaci_veljavne([308.412, 308.416]), [False] * 2) self.assertEqual(oznaci_veljavne([205.134, 205.182, 205.190, 205.207, 250.13, 250.83, 251.6, 308.412, 308.416]), [False] * 4 + [True] * 3 + [False] * 2) self.assertEqual(oznaci_veljavne([205.134, 205.182, 308.416]), [False] * 2 + [True]) self.assertEqual(oznaci_veljavne([205.134, 205.182, 308.416, 308.999]), [False] * 2 + [True] * 2) self.assertEqual(oznaci_veljavne([100, 100.8, 205.134, 205.182, 308.416, 308.999]), [True] * 2 + [False] * 2 + [True] * 2) self.assertEqual(oznaci_veljavne([100, 100.8, 205.134, 205.182]), [True] * 2 + [False] * 2) self.assertEqual(oznaci_veljavne([100, 205.134, 205.182, 205.190, 205.207, 250.13, 250.83, 251.6, 308.412, 308.416]), [True] + [False] * 4 + [True] * 3 + [False] * 2) self.assertEqual(oznaci_veljavne([100, 205.134, 205.182, 205.190, 205.207, 250.13, 250.83, 251.6, 308.412, 308.416, 500]), [True] + [False] * 4 + [True] * 3 + [False] * 2 + [True]) self.assertSequenceEqual(oznaci_veljavne([ 5.18, 5.907, 6.632, 7.215, 132.3, 132.94, 183.12, 205.134, 205.182, 205.190, 205.207, 308.412, 308.416, 512.73, 513.20, 513.65, 918.2, 918.73]), [True] * 4 + [True] * 2 + [True] + [False] * 4 + [False] * 2 + [True] * 3 + [True] * 2)
```

Comment: It will be great if you can provide the sample input list and the desired output list

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! People will be able to help you better if you provide examples of what you've tried so far and why these attempts haven't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write a *list comprehension* expression as:

```
[j-i<0.1 for i, j in zip(my_list[:-1], my_list[1:])]
```

This will create new list with value as:

- `True` if difference between two consecutive element is less than 0.1
- `False` if difference is more than or equal to 0.1

Sample run:

```
>>> my_list = [1.00, 1.02, 1.05, 1.3, 1.34, 1.51, 1.54]
>>> [j-i<0.1 for i, j in zip(my_list[:-1], my_list[1:])]
[True, True, False, True, False, True]
```

Comment: Then your answer will be `True` + answer result by the list comprehension that I have given. Because first value will always be valid, and rest of the values are dependent on the previous value.

Comment: Since i accidentaly removed my last comments: The task is about measuring hamsters run on his wheel. The input list contains measurement in seconds of each spin and the function "validates" each of them. So if they are closer than 0.1 sencond the measurements if False (impossible).